# Best practice to document parameters of parameters using Javadoc, e.g. for callback functions

Tags: java, lambda, javadoc

Whenever I need to document the exact nature of parameters passed to functions that are method parameters themselves (usually using functional interfaces), I tend to just describe it inside the `@param` tag. Depending on the complexity of such functions, this can result in pretty long descriptions.

For example, how shall I communicate to a API users, what meaning `x` has if I want them to pass some `x -> {}`:

```java
/**
 * Does something.
 * 
 * @param callback A callback that will be invoked with a param x once something has been done. X will be 42 if something was done successfully on a Monday. Otherwise it'll be 23.
 *
 * ...
 */
void doSomething(Consumer<Integer> callback) {...}
```

Other than defining a new interface for each callback, is there any other way to document these "parameters of parameters" more formally?

**Edit:**
Apparently my question was unclear: The above is an *example*, that means it is only used to show the impact of the broader topic. I don't want to document `Consumer` in particular. This is a general question that applies to *any* functional interface that allows passing lambdas as parameters to a function.

The generic javadoc for the various functional interfaces in `java.util.function.*` is certainly *not* meant to document the meaning of the parameters, since they vastly depend on the context. For example [the mappingFunction in HashMap.computeIfAbsent(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) has, obviously, a different description than the [mapper in LogManager.updateConfiguration(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#updateConfiguration(java.util.function.Function)), despite using the same interface.

Comment: `Consumer` already has its own Javadoc, or it should have. You don't have to repeat any of that. All you have to do here is describe how it will be used by the method you're documenting here.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Maybe the question was misleading, so I made clear this is not about Javadoc of `java.util.function.*` interfaces but rather about functional parameters.

Comment: As you can see, the JDK documents functional interface parameters in much the same way as you're already doing. The `Map#computeIfAbsent` method documents the full behavior in the method description and then gives an overview in the `@param` description. The `LogManager#updateConfiguration` method instead documents the full behavior in the `@param` description. You can also look at other examples (e.g. both `Stream` and `CompletionStage` make heavy use of functional interfaces).

Comment: @Slaw That is part of the reason why I referenced them. However, I was hoping there is a better (as in: more structured) way.

Comment: As far as I know, the standard Doclet does not provide anything more in this regard. If there was an option then I would assume the JDK would use it (they already have [their own, non-standard tags](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8068562)). You might be able to do something with custom [Taglets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/jdk/javadoc/doclet) but not sure.